# How do I put connection string with IP Address inside web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

We are currently using the following connection string in our web.config file:

```
add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ourServer;Initial Catalog=ourDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=theUserName;Password=thePassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This works fine. However, this app needs to be pushed to our external server. This means, according to our infrastructure team that we will need a connection string with ip address and port 1433 to be able to connect the app to our db which is not on the same external server.

I have tried any of the two connection strings below but they don't work.

The first one doesn't error out but just doesn't recognize the db. I suspect it is because of this bit

```
tcp:10.database.windows.net
```

Do I need to replace it with IP Address? I am told I need the tcp in there.

```
<add name="DBConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:10.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=POLLWORKER_TRAINING;Integrated Security=False;User Id=pworker;Password=pworker;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

This last one is causing an error which says,

> the element connectionStrings cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected, "add", "remove", "clear"

```
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=sqloledb;Data=10.22.5.20,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=ourDB;User ID=theUserName;Password=thePassword" />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This `Data=10.22.5.20,1433` in your connection string should be:

`Data Source=10.22.5.20,1433`

For more details see: [SQL Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Comment: thank you very much sir for your prompt response.

I added that correction you made but still getting following error:

`Parser Error Message: The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element.` pointing to the correction strings entry.

Comment: @Kenny, what is your connection string now ?

Comment: My fault sir, very sorry. The error was caused by me. I am testing now. No more errors