# ASP.NET Connection String Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

I have a Sql Server 2008 R2 connection string that looks like

```
  <add name="DBConnectionString"
Data Source=XXXX;uid=rp1;pwd=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;"/>
```

When trying to create a new instance of SQLDatabase using EnterpriseLibrary.Data I get the above error.

```
connString =ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"];
Database objDB = new SqlDatabase(connString);
```

connString has the following

```
Data Source=AYZ;Initial Catalog=AYZ;User ID=AYZ;Password=AYZ;
```

The detailed exception is as follows :

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DecryptConnectionString(String strEncyptConStr)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database..ctor(String connectionString, DbProviderFactory dbProviderFactory)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase..ctor(String connectionString)
       at ABC.GRC.DAL.CommonDAL..ctor() in D:\ABC\Projects\Right Price\ABC.GRC\ABC.GRC\ABC.GRC.DAL\CommonDAL.cs:line 31
       at ABC.GRC.BLL.CommonBLL..ctor() in D:\ABC\Projects\Right Price\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC.BLL\CommonBLL.cs:line 14
       at Global.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\ABC\Projects\Right Price\ABC.GRC\ABC.GRC\ABC.GRC.WEB\App_Code\Global.asax.cs:line 60
       at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()
  InnerException:
```

I have also tried by encrypting the connection string. It still returns the same error.
I have also tried hardcoding the connection string.

Comment: your format of the DBConnectionString is wrong... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639760/how-do-i-put-connection-string-with-ip-address-inside-web-config-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Character in Base-64 String” using ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682777/invalid-character-in-base-64-string-using-asp-net)

Comment: You're still asking the same question over and over again - even though you already got tons of answers and even accepted one of them!

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682777/invalid-character-in-base-64-string-using-asp-net

Comment: Your original post contained the password. This is still visible in the edit history. **CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD IMMEDIATELY**.

Comment: I have changed the password. None of the answers have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

in Connection String